# How to re flash android 2.3?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rom-flashing, graphics

I have a Galaxy POP running android 2.3 Ginger Bread. Recently the display of my phone got messed up. The lower part of the screen just turns white with a some black dots on it. The touch on that part works fine though! I think its the problem of the OS. Therefore i'm considering of re flashing it but have no clue on how to go about it! Please help

Comment: Why should re-flashing a read-only file system (the Android OS resides in `/system`, which is read only) help, and what should have changed there? That looks like a classical [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your question should describe the real problem (display) and ask for a solution instead :) Alas: Have you tried a factory-reset already, which would clean up the system (but also remove your data and apps)?

Comment: It's not `read only` - it can be written to, otherwise there'd be nothing there.  It may be seen as read only as far as user apps go, but it's not impossible for the OS itself to have messed it up.  In this case, flashing back a known working ROM would be a way of ruling this out.  (It sounds like a hardware problem to me.)

Comment: Can you post a picture concerning the black spots? I believe its just the screen not the OS itself that has the problem

Comment: Right now the OS freezes when I switch on the phone. But the phone can receive any incoming calls. If attend the call the phone unfreezes but if i reject it, it again freezes! I know it sounds pretty weird but thats the situation with my phone now! :/ And thats the reason I thought the problem might be with the OS and not the hardware!